# C# Unity not displaying Debug.Log() console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am writing a script that shows a collision between one object and an obstacle. The code runs but does not output within the console. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class collision : MonoBehaviour{

    void OnConllisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle") 
        { 
            Debug.Log("We Hit an obstacle!");
        }
    }
    
}
```

I added a tag to the object as I will be adding more obstacles to simplify the process. I checked for semicolons and any other errors that would stand out to me. I am not sure what I am supposed to change or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a typo in the methods name

```cs
//       Here
//        |
//        v
void OnConllisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
```

The code should be

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class collision : MonoBehaviour{

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle") 
        { 
            Debug.Log("We Hit an obstacle!");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using OnConllisionEnter, check your collider component to make sure the [Is Trigger] flag isn't checked
[Collider Component, Is Trigger Flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB0Ed.png)

Also, remember that both objects have to have a collider component attached to them and only one of them will need a rigid body component attached to it (both of which have to match the correct world space, i.e. 2D/3D RigidBody and Collider.

More about Collisions:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).